# Eclipse RCP 4 app, how to remove "Preferences" in Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, eclipse-rcp

I'm making an app based on Eclipse RCP 4.

When I run the app on a Mac OSX, a new Menu button with the app name appears with an "About" and "Preferences" tab. I need to disable the "Preferences" tab.

I've been looking online for hours without success.

Does anyone know how can I disable/remove it?

Comment: Never seen anything about suppressing this. Your app isn't going to look like a proper MacOS app without the Preferences as just about everything has it.

Comment: But if my application doesn't have any preferences, it doesn't make sense to have an available "Preferences" tab.